# Error when uploading a .aspx file on the server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am getting a runtime error when i upload an .aspx file on my server. I uploaded files before  of the same format and they were working fine so my server does support this service.
Also, the application is working fine on my local server.

This is the error:
Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

And this is my code:

> ```
> <%@ Page Language="C#" %> <%@ import Namespace="System.IO" %> <%@ import Namespace="System" %> <%@ import
> ```
>
> Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %> <%@ import
>   Namespace="System.Linq" %> <%@ import Namespace="System.Web" %> <%@
>   import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %> <%@ import
>   Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
>
> ```
> public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     //This a program that calculates your mortgage payments
>
>     //Variables used 
>     double p;
>     double m = 0;
>     double rate = 0;
>     int years = 0;
>     int ny = 0;
>     bool result = false;
>
>      rate = DropDownList2.SelectedIndex;    //Here we get the values from the comboBox1 and assign it to the variable "rate"
>
>
>     //The following IF statements get the value from the radio buttons and assign it to the variable "years"
>
>     if (RadioButtonList2.SelectedIndex == 0)
>     {
>         years = 15;
>
>     }
>     if (RadioButtonList2.SelectedIndex == 1)
>     {
>         years = 30;
>
>     }
>     if (RadioButtonList2.SelectedIndex == 2 && TextBox5.Text != null)
>     {
>         if (int.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, out ny))
>         {
>             years = ny;
>         }
>
>     }
>
>
>     //A simple if statement to check if the user filled out all values necessary for the calculation.
>     //if any of the values where wrong or missing the program prompts the user to check his/her input again
>
>     if (years != 0 && rate != 0 && double.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, out p))
>     {
>         m = (p * rate / 1200.0) / (1 - Math.Pow((1.0 + rate / 1200.0), -12.0 * years));
>         result = true;
>
>
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         TextBox6.Text = "Please fill all boxes!";
>     }
>
>
>     //If all of the above steps checks true then the payment amount is displayed on textBox3
>     if (result == true)
>     {
>         TextBox6.Text = m + "";
>         StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("d:/log_file.txt");
>         sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "\nAmount: " + m + "");
>         sw.WriteLine();
>         sw.Close();
>     }
>
> }
>
> public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     TextBox4.Text = null;
>     TextBox5.Text = null;
>     TextBox6.Text = null;
>     RadioButtonList2.SelectedIndex = 0;
> }
> public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>
> } </script>
> ```
>
> ```
>   <script src="css_browser_selector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> ```
>
> Geo Nicolaides | Monthly Payments
>
> $(document).ready(function () {
>           $('#page_effect').fadeIn(500);
>       });
>
> George Nicolaides
>          IT-330
>
> ```
> <div class="footer">
>
>   <div id="nav">
>
>       <div class="navlist1">
>
>           <ul> <li> <a class="navlist" href="index.html">Home</a> </li></ul>
>
>       </div>
>
>      <div class="navlist1">
>
>           <ul> <li><a class="active" href="projects.html" >Projects</a></li> </ul>
>
>       </div>
>
>
>
>         <div class="navlist1">
>
>           <ul> <li><a class="navlist" href="view-log.aspx" >Log Files</a></li> </ul>
>
>       </div>          
>
>
>
>   </div>
>
>
>
> </div> </div>
> ```
>
> ```
> <div class="wrapper2">            
>
>
>
>
>
> <div class="content">
>
> <div id="page_effect" style="display:none;">
> ```
>
> ```
>     <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Years of payments:" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
>     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server" style="margin-left:0px; color:White;">
>         <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
>         <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
>         <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
>     </asp:RadioButtonList>
>     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" style="margin-left:0px" Width="47px"></asp:TextBox>
> <br />
>     <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Interest Rate" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>    <br />
>     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Height="23px" 
>         style="margin-left: 0px">
>         <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Rate</asp:ListItem>
>         <asp:ListItem>3.0</asp:ListItem>
>         <asp:ListItem>3.5</asp:ListItem>
>         <asp:ListItem>4.0</asp:ListItem>
>         <asp:ListItem>4.5</asp:ListItem>
>         <asp:ListItem>5.0</asp:ListItem>
>         <asp:ListItem>5.5</asp:ListItem>
>         <asp:ListItem>6.0</asp:ListItem>
>     </asp:DropDownList>
>   <br /> <br />
>
>     <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" 
>         Text="Calculate" onclick="Button1_Click" ForeColor="Black" 
>     Height="37px" Width="119px"  />
>
>  <br /> <br />
>
>     <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Monthly Payment:" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
>     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" 
>         AutoPostBack="True" BackColor="White" Columns="50" ReadOnly="True" 
>         ViewStateMode="Enabled" Width="142px"></asp:TextBox>
> <br />
>   <br />
>     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" 
>         Text="Reset" onclick="Button2_Click" ForeColor="Black" 
>     Height="37px" Width="119px"  />
>
>  <br /> <br />
>
>     <div class="largespacebelow">
>
>
>   </div>            
>
>
>
>   </div>
>
>   </div>
>
>   </div>
>
>
>
>   <div class="push2">
> ```

Comment: remove your custom error settings from the web.config to see the details of the error. Then post that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step should be to get the 'real' error. If you have local/GUI access to the server, log in and try to browse to the page at localhost.

Otherwise, you should edit your web.config to set the customerrors mode to off so you can see the detailed error report remotely. Note: Do not do this if you are worried about security implications, but I'm assuming this isn't any sort of live high-traffic public website.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) is the page about the customerrors web.config element, but basically you just flip the "mode" bit to "off". That should give you a lot more information to work with.

One thing I notice after a once-over of your code (and this may just be because the formatting is all kinds of screwed up), but I don't see an opening `<script>` tag before your button1_click method. You should also consider moving all of the C# to a [code-behind](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303247) file to separate the logic and design and make everything easier to read and maintain.

Comment: That is the way I had it before but the specs that I have do not allow me to separate the code. I might have pasted the code here wrong but I can assure that the application is working just fine on my local server. I will try and log on the server via remote desktop and check if I have this kind of permissions to view the file locally. Thanks.

Comment: Nop, the remote access to the server is disabled. I will try the config file and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

I had a wrong Namespace on the top of my site.